# Highlight input when it gets filled (angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Right now, I have an input like this

```
<input class="share-link" ng-model="share_link">
```

and I have a `$http.get` which changes the variable and fills in the input based on the result. What I would like to do is have it so that the input gets selected when this happens.

My thoughts are to put in `ng-change`, find the input, and call `.select` on it. However, it seems `ng-change` only gets fired when the user actually types in the box, not when the model changes.

Additionally, I don't know how to actually find the input when the action gets called. I tried to pass `this`, but that seems to only pass the scope. There are multiple of these inputs on the page, and I only want to select the relevant one, so I can't just use `document.querySelector` or something like it.

How should I do this?

Comment: have the shared link in the $scope of the controller. And add ng-focus to the input tag.

Comment: `ng-focus`! Thank you! Could you write an answer so I could mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `focus()` method.

```
document.getElementByClassName('share-link').focus();
```

Comment: As I said, there are multiple `.share-link`s on the page. My issue isn't knowing the `focus` method; it's the selection method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-focus` to do this. And for more documentation refer to the following.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus

One simple example

http://jsfiddle.net/deathhell/UTn5y/2/